# Fonctionnement formulaire contrôlé react?

Tags: reactjs, forms

I have a problem with react. with a form, I created more inputs that are controlled. I created a function that runs when the form changes. which but updates a state. but reacte gives me an error.

```
VM2529 react_devtools_backend.js:4026 Warning: A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.
```

handleChange func:

```
    let DefaultValue = {
        firsName: '',
        lastname: '',
        email: '',
        message: ''
    }

    const [output, setOutput] = useState(DefaultValue)

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setOutput({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    }
```

thank you for your reply.

Comment: You are not posting enough code for anyone to consider your issue, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setOutput({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
```

This will not be merged with the old state, it will *replace* the old state. So if they change `lastName`, the new state will be `{ lastName: "some string" }`, and all other values will be undefined.

Instead, you need to copy all the other values from the old state:

```
setOutput(prev => ({
  ...prev,
  [e.target.name]: e.target.value
});
```

Comment: Perfect everything works fine. I understood my mistake .